# HTAccess Rewrite URL removing the directory Information, i.e. Webpage in Root directory

Tags: url-rewriting

I have product item webpages located in /product/items/*.html?id=12345&ref=54321 and I would like the webpages to be displayed as being in the Root directory with the same filenames and query string.

I have tried Rule Generators and changing my current HTAccess, but nothing to seems to quite get the job done.

Comment: e.g. www.domain.com/product/items/item1.html to appear to the user to be located at www.domain.com/item1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using the alias directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

It allows you to map a directory to a different URL path, so you use `Alias /example /product/items` to access `/product/items/item1.html` via the URL `www.domain.com/example/item1.html`

I haven't tested this, but I assume that `Alias / /product/items` would allow you to use `www.domain.com/item1.html`